# Defining iterative algorithms

Tags: syntax, core-language, algorithm, iterators

Assume the iterative algorithm of interest to be as follows:

```
Tin = {{-3/4, 1/4}, {5, -6}};
tin = {2/4, 1};
pin = {.7, .3};

(*For initial: first row is Tu, second tu, third pu*)

iterate[{Tu_, tu_, pu_}] := {
  l = (tu.tu);
  a = Tu.Transpose[Tu].tu.tu;
  {{{a, l}, {l + 1, a + 1}},
   {a, l^2},
   {a, l}}
  }
```

Where the objective is to use the new values of Tu, tu, and pu as derived from the previous iteration as the input values for the next (in this case,

```
 {{{a, l}, {l + 1, a + 1}}, {a, l^2}, {a, l}}
```

constitute the input values to be used as `Tu,tu,pu` for the next iteration, respectively, presented as a list).

Indeed,

```
Nest[iterate, {Tin, tin, pin}, 1]
```

> ```
> {{{{1789/32, 5/4}, {9/4, 1821/32}}, {1789/32, 25/16}, {1789/32, 5/4}}}
> ```

Gives us exactly what we are looking for in iteration 1, however:

```
Nest[iterate, {Tin, tin, pin}, 2]
```

> iterate[{{{{1789/32, 5/4}, {9/4, 1821/32}}, {1789/32, 25/16}, {1789/32, 5/4}}}]

is obviously not what we are looking for (it did not take the new values from the previous iteration as its input, rather it is applying `iterate` over the correct ordered list

```
{{{{1789/32, 5/4}, {9/4, 1821/32}}, {1789/32, 25/16}, {1789/32, 5/4}}}
```

Is there something else I should be doing in this case?

Comment: `{{{{1789/32, 5/4}, {9/4, 1821/32}}, {1789/32, 25/16}, {1789/
   32, 5/4}}}` is a list of length 1, but the argument pattern for `iterate` matches a list of length 3, so evaluation is not triggered. Perhaps you have one too many layers of `{}`.

Comment: It does seem to be the case that an extra layer of brackets is being evaluated. How would I then, say, make it such that ` {{{a, l}, {l + 1, a + 1}},
   {a, l^2},
   {a, l}}` is put out without the additional `{}`  wrapping it?

Comment: @Janeiro Multi-line functions in Mathematica should actually be wrapped in parentheses `( )` rather than curly braces `{ }` as curly braces defines lists.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that fixed it!

Comment: @Janeiro No problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have made a simple mistake in defining `iterate`. Try this:

```
iterate[{Tu_, tu_, pu_}] :=
  Module[{l, a},
    l = (tu.tu);
    a = Tu.Transpose[Tu].tu.tu;
    {{{a, l}, {l + 1, a + 1}}, {a, l^2}, {a, l}}]
```

Then

```
Tin = {{-3/4, 1/4}, {5, -6}};
tin = {2/4, 1};
pin = {.7, .3};

Nest[iterate, {Tin, tin, pin}, 2]
```

gives

> ```
> {{{10292833394741/1048576, 3203021/1024}, {3204045/1024, 10292834443317/1048576}}, 
>  {10292833394741/1048576, 10259343526441/1048576}, 
>  {10292833394741/1048576, 3203021/1024}}
> ```

Is that the result you expect?